# how to print a formula like "1+(3-2)" in haskell?

Tags: haskell

how do i solve this problem in haskell?

"
A machine selects an integral number ( more than or equal to one and less than or equal to N)
with equal probability at one operation.
Find the  excepted probability in which the median of three integral number
selected by three times operation with the machine above is K. (K is also integral number)
"

first i tried this and got this error:

```
main = do

    n <- getLine
    k <- getLine

    print 1+(n-1)+(n-1)*(n-2)/n^3
```

q4.hs:7:18:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO ()’
    Expected type: IO ()
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(n - 1)’

q4.hs:7:24:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO ()’
    Expected type: IO ()
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘n’
    In the first argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘(n - 1)’

q4.hs:7:30:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO ()’
    Expected type: IO ()
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘(n - 2)’

q4.hs:7:35:
    Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘IO ()’
    Expected type: IO ()
      Actual type: String
    In the first argument of ‘(^)’, namely ‘n’
    In the second argument of ‘(/)’, namely ‘n ^ 3’

how do i solve this problem?
sorry i'm very new to haskell(and english too.) 
thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The first level of problems can be solved by adding parentheses to group the argument to `print` (or by using `$`):

```
main = do
    n <- getLine
    k <- getLine
    print (1+(n-1)+(n-1)*(n-2)/n^3)
    -- OR
    print $ 1+(n-1)+(n-1)*(n-2)/n^3
```

The next level of problems is that `n` is a `String`, but you're hoping for it to be some kind of number. You can fix this by using `readLn` instead of `getLine` and specifying what type you want to use; for example:

```
main = do
    n <- readLn :: IO Double
    k <- getLine
    print $ 1+(n-1)+(n-1)*(n-2)/n^3
```

Comment: Of course, the third problem is that `k` is probably supposed to be used for something, and the fourth is that it's impossible to tell from the problem description whether the math is as intended.